# Finding the regular language of the following expressions

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

What is the regular language of the following example:

`S-> aT | bS | lambda
T-> bA | aT | lambda
A-> bS | lambda`

Thanks.

Comment: $(a|b)^*$ probably

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated than that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deterministic automaton associated to this grammar is represented below.
It is not difficult now to see that the language accepted by this automaton is
$(aa^*b^2 + b)^*(a^* + a^+b)$.

[image]

Comment: Wow, This is very impressive. Thank you very much.